# new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build() hangs indefinitely

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I am using mocha and selenium to do end to end integration testing. I am using beforeEach and afterEach hook to initialize browser and kill it after each test. Here is my js file which has both the methods

```
require('chromedriver')

// globals
global.assert = require('assert')
global.driver = null
const { Builder, By, until, promise } = require('selenium-webdriver')


// setup
beforeEach(async function () {
  this.timeout(utils.DEFAULT_TEST_TIMEOUT)
  while (driver !== null) {
    console.log('waiting for driver to quit from last test')
    await utils.sleep(1000)
  }
  try {
    driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build()
    await driver.manage().window().setSize(1600, 900)
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex.stack)
  }

})

afterEach(async function () {
  this.timeout(utils.DEFAULT_TEST_TIMEOUT)
  if (driver === null) {
    console.log('some problem in before each of the test ' + this.currentTest.title + ' returning...')
    return
  }
  await saveScreenShot(SCREENSHOTS_PATH + this.currentTest.parent.title, this.currentTest.title)
  await driver.quit()
  driver = null
})
```

Now when i run the test suit on jenkins i very frequently see this ("email already registered" is a test name)

```
✓ email domain not allowed (4167ms)
    1) "before each" hook for "email already registered"
some problem in before each of the test email already registered returning...


  39 passing (9m)
  1 pending
  1 failing

  1)  "before each" hook for "email already registered":
     Error: Timeout of 60000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

The thing to notice is that once this error comes the subsequent tests do not run. My test suit has 100s of tests and in the run above it quit once it encountered this beforeEach error and didn't run next set of tests.

I have tried various things but nothing seems to work. Any pointer in debugging this will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The beforeEach is never resolving and causing the test to timeout. You must signify either through a resolved promise or calling a done() callback function that the beforeEach has finished.

You can do either one of the following:

wrap the body of the beforeEach in returning a new Promise as such:

```
beforeEach(async function () {
  return new Promise(async (resolve,reject) => {
    this.timeout(60000)
    try {
      driver = await new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build()
      await driver.manage().window().setSize(1600, 900)
      resolve()
    } catch (ex) {
      reject(ex.stack)
    }
  })
})
```

OR you can add the done() callback function to your beforeEach definition:

```
beforeEach(async function (done) {
  this.timeout(60000)
  try {
    driver = await new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build()
    await driver.manage().window().setSize(1600, 900)
    done();
  } catch (ex) {
    done(ex.stack)
  }
})
```

I didn't test these, but either of them should work.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i tried the first solution and i still see the same problem. When i try the second one i get this error

 1)  "before each" hook for "Admin shown correctly":
     Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation now for selenium-webdriver. I could be mistaken but it doesn't look like the construction of a new webdriver is not asynchronous? Maybe you could try removing the awaits you have in place?

Comment: One question i had was, with the returning promise solution, do beforeEach and afterEach need to be async?

Comment: beforeEach and afterEach do not need to be async. But using await implies that you are executing asynchronous functions. Also I think declaring the function async in beforEach/afterEach they will expect a promise resolved. If you removed the async declaration, and removed the awaits then it would be executed synchronously for example.